# Importance of "independent" under-graduate research in graduate admissions

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-undergraduate, independent-researcher

By independent research I mean, the research was not done with some organization or under a professor. I and my roommate tried out some new things that we thought to get published. My ultimate aim would be getting into research.

Though, I also have a paper published where the I did my work under the supervision of a professor.

But I was wondering if sharing the experience of independent research in a Statement of Purpose really matters while applying for masters ?

Comment: What's important is the quality of the peer-reviewed published paper.

Answer (score 6):

In an application, list all material that shows you in a positive light. Being able to perform successful research, both on your own and under supervision, is good. The fact that you engaged, on your own (or with friends) on research and were able to publish it (I assume in a peer-reviewed journal) is a plus for your application… unless the quality of the paper is really (visibly) bad.